# Life span and injection of @SessionAttributes object in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm unclear on some subtleties of using `@SessionAttributes` in Spring MVC via Spring Boot 2.3.3.RELEASE.

- I have two controllers, `Step1Controller` and `Step2Controller`.
- Both controllers use `@SessionAttributes("foobar")` at the class level.
- `Step1Controller` during its request handling for `@PostMapping` adds a special `FooBar` instance to the model using `model.addAttribute("foobar", new FooBar("foo", "bar"))`.
- `Step2Controller`, invoked under a completely independent HTTP `POST`, picks up the `FooBar` instance in its `@PostMapping` service method using `doSomething(FooBar fooBar)`.
- This all words great!

But I'm unclear on some details of *why* it works.

The `@SessionAttributes` API documentation says in part:

> Those attributes will be removed once the handler indicates completion of its conversational session. Therefore, use this facility for such conversational attributes which are supposed to be stored in the session *temporarily* during the course of a specific handler's conversation. For permanent session attributes, e.g. a user authentication object, use the traditional `session.setAttribute` method instead.

1. If `@SessionAttributes` only stores model attributes in the HTTP session temporarily and removes them at the end of the conversation, why does `foobar` still show up in the request to `Step2Controller`? It appears to me to still be in the session. I don't understand what the docs mean when they refer to "temporarily" and "handler's conversation". It would appear `foobar` is stored in the session normally.
2. It would appear that simply by having `@SessionAttributes("foobar")` on `Step1Controller`, Spring will automatically copy `foobar` from the model to the session after handling the request. That was sort of hinted at in the documentation, but it only became clear to me through experimentation.
3. It would appear that by placing `@SessionAttributes("foobar")` on `Step2Controller`, Spring copies `foobar` *from* the session *to* the model *before* the request. This was not clear to me at all from the documentation.
4. And finally, note that in `Step2Controller.doSomething(FooBar fooBar)` *I don't have any annotation at all on the `FooBar` parameter*, other than the `@SessionAttributes("foobar")` (but that is on the controller class). The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args) seemed to indicate I need to add a `@ModelAttribute` annotation to the method parameter, such as `Step2Controller.doSomething(@ModelAttribute("foobar") FooBar fooBar)` or at least `Step2Controller.doSomething(@ModelAttribute FooBar fooBar)`. But Spring still seems to find the session variable, even with no annotation at all on the parameter. Why? How would I have known this?

This is on of the things that has always bugged me about Spring: too many things happen "magically", with no clear documentation of what is expected to happen. People who use Spring for years I suppose just get a "feel" for what works and doesn't; but a new developer looking at the code just has to trust that it magically does what it's supposed to.

Why does what I have described work, especially in reference to the first question? Maybe that way I too can develop this "Spring sense" to instinctively know which incantations to evoke.

Comment: I think this is a good question at it's heart, but I'd change 2 things: rather than bullet pointing how your code looks, just show us. "Show don't tell" applies to StackOverflow too. Your 2nd to last paragraph also just strikes me as a bit of a moan, I don't see what it's really adding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*this answer has two parts*

1. *Giving some general information about `SessionAttributes`*
2. *Going through the question itself*

#### `@SessionAttributes` in Spring

The [`@SessionAttributes`'s javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/SessionAttributes.html) states that it should be used to store attributes temporarily:

> use this facility for such conversational attributes which are supposed to be stored in the session *temporarily* during the course of a specific handler's conversation.

Temporal boundaries of such a "conversation" are defined by programmer explicitly, or to be more exact: **programmer defines completion of conversation**, they can do it via [`SessionStatus`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/support/SessionStatus.html). [Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-sessionattributes) is relevant part of documentation and example:

> On the first request, when a model attribute with the name, `pet`, is added to the model, it is automatically promoted to and saved in the HTTP Servlet session. **It remains there until another controller method uses a `SessionStatus` method argument to clear the storage**, as the following example shows:

```java
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("pet") 
public class EditPetForm {
    @PostMapping("/pets/{id}")
    public String handle(Pet pet, BindingResult errors, SessionStatus status) {
        if (errors.hasErrors) {
            // ...
        }
        status.setComplete(); 
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you want to dig deep you can study the source code of:

- [`SessionAttributesHandler`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/SessionAttributesHandler.java)

#### Going through the question

> 1. If `@SessionAttributes` only stores model attributes in the HTTP session temporarily and removes them at the end of the conversation, why does `foobar` still show up in the request to `Step2Controller`?

Because, most probably you have not defined conversation completion.

> It appears to me to still be in the session.

Exactly

> I don't understand what the docs mean when they refer to "temporarily" and "handler's conversation".

I *guess* it's somehow related to the [Spring WebFlow](https://projects.spring.io/spring-webflow/). (See [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-web-flow) introductory article)

> It would appear `foobar` is stored in the session normally.

Yes, see [`DefaultSessionAttributeStore`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/bind/support/DefaultSessionAttributeStore.java)

You may ask here: **What does make some session attributes temporal and some not? How are they distinguished?**. The answer may be found in the source code:

[`SessionAttributesHandler.java`#L146](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/7bc803598967ab9d5bf1eb378bd7b7c4bf212f15/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/SessionAttributesHandler.java#L146):

```java
/**
 * Remove "known" attributes from the session, i.e. attributes listed
 * by name in {@code @SessionAttributes} or attributes previously stored
 * in the model that matched by type.
 * @param request the current request
 */
public void cleanupAttributes(WebRequest request) {
    for (String attributeName : this.knownAttributeNames) {
        this.sessionAttributeStore.cleanupAttribute(request, attributeName);
    }
}
```

> 2. It would appear that simply by having `@SessionAttributes("foobar")` on `Step1Controller`, Spring will automatically copy `foobar` from the model to the session after handling the request.

[Yes, it will](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/7bc803598967ab9d5bf1eb378bd7b7c4bf212f15/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/SessionAttributesHandler.java#L108)

> 3. It would appear that by placing `@SessionAttributes("foobar")` on `Step2Controller`, Spring copies `foobar` *from* the session *to* the model *before* the request.

[Also true](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/ModelFactory.java#L111)

> 4. And finally, note that in `Step2Controller.doSomething(FooBar fooBar)` *I don't have any annotation at all on the `FooBar` parameter*, other than the `@SessionAttributes("foobar")` (but that is on the controller class). The documentation seemed to indicate I need to add a `@ModelAttribute` annotation to the method parameter, such as `Step2Controller.doSomething(@ModelAttribute("foobar") FooBar fooBar)` or at least `Step2Controller.doSomething(@ModelAttribute FooBar fooBar)`. But Spring still seems to find the session variable, even with no annotation at all on the parameter. Why? How would I have known this?

See [Method Arguments](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments) section:

> If a method argument is not matched to any of the earlier values in this table and it is a simple type (as determined by BeanUtils#isSimpleProperty, it is a resolved as a @RequestParam. Otherwise, it is resolved as a @ModelAttribute.

> This is on of the things that has always bugged me about Spring: too many things happen "magically", with no clear documentation of what is expected to happen. People who use Spring for years I suppose just get a "feel" for what works and doesn't; but a new developer looking at the code just has to trust that it magically does what it's supposed to.

*Here I would suggest going through the reference documentation, it can give a clue how can you describe some specific behavior of Spring*

---

**10/11/2020 update**:

> Denis, does this ability to automatically apply an argument from the model as a method argument only work with interfaces? I've found that if FooBar is an interface, Step2Controller.doSomething(FooBar fooBar) works as discussed above    . But if FooBar is a class, even if I have an instance of FooBar in the model, Step2Controller.doSomething(FooBar fooBar) results in a "No primary or default constructor found for class FooBar" exception. Even @ModelAttribute won't wor    k. I have to use @ModelAttribute("foobar"). Why do classes work differently from interfaces in parameter substitution?

This sounds to me, that there is some issue with naming/`@SessionAttributes#names`.

I've created a [sample project](https://github.com/cac03/sessionlifespan) to demonstrate where the problem may be hidden.

The project has two parts:

1. Attempts to use class
2. Attempts to use an interface

The entry point to the project are the two tests (see `ClassFooBarControllerTest` and `InterfaceFooBarControllerTest`)

I've left comments to explain what is happening here

Comment: caco3, this is an amazing answer that really clears up a lot of things and points me to the right places. I'm going to add a bounty to the question as a reward for all your work. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful

Comment: Denis, does this ability to automatically apply an argument from the model as a method argument only work with interfaces? I've found that if `FooBar` is an interface, `Step2Controller.doSomething(FooBar fooBar)` works as discussed above. But if `FooBar` is a class, even if I have an instance of `FooBar` in the model, `Step2Controller.doSomething(FooBar fooBar)` results in a "No primary or default constructor found for class FooBar" exception. Even `@ModelAttribute` won't work. I have to use `@ModelAttribute("foobar")`. Why do classes work differently from interfaces in parameter substitution?

Comment: @GarretWilson, I've updated my answer. I'm not sure where exactly the problem lies, so I've created a sample project, which may give you some hints. Currently I'm suspecting, that you have some issues with implicit names. Feel free to modify the project and ask once again if the project does not help you

Comment: Thanks, Denis. But there can't be a typo in the name, because I'm using a string constant throughout. Your sample didn't quite reproduce the situation. Most importantly your `FooBar` class has a no-args constructor, so how could it produce the error I showed? Try this: 1) remove the `FooBar` no-args constructor, 2) in `Controller1`, create a `FooBar` instance and put it in the model with the key `"foobar"`, 3) in `Controller2`, reference a `FooBar` type in the `GET` or `PUT` mapping method, but with no annotation whatsoever. (Both controllers have a `@SessionAttributes("foobar")` of course.)

Comment: Meanwhile I'll simply annotate the parameter with foobar `@ModelAttribute("foobar")`; that seems to work fine. I didn't mean to bother you with debugging my code. I was just curious as to why Spring seemed to automatically inject interface-based parameters from the model without needing a named `@ModelAttribute` annotation, but not concrete class-based parameters; and wondered if you knew anything about that. Thanks again.

Comment: Here's the odd thing I'm finding. If I have `controller1` _redirect_ to `view1`, then `view1` can't see `foobar` in the model; I have to pass it in a flash attribute. But if `view2` posts to `controller2`, then `controller2` can't see the flash attribute (I understand it's been removed already), so `controller1` has to put `foobar` in the model, which `controller2` _can_ see (even though `view1` cannot see it). So `controller1` has to put `foobar` in both a flash attribute (so that `view1` can see it) and in the model as well (so that `controller2` can see it when `view2` does a `POST` to it).

Comment: To summarize my previous comment: if a view template is exposed and accessed directly via a `GET`, for some reason it doesn't have access to the same model attributes that a controller would if it were accessed directly via `GET`. Perhaps it's the lack of way to specify a `@SessionAttributes` for a view. Normally this wouldn't even be an issue because one wouldn't access a view directly, but with the "Post/Redirect/Get" pattern it becomes an issue. In any case it doesn't seem clear and straightforward to me. But I think I have it working.

Comment: Can you please share your sample project? :)

Comment: Sorry, I can't share this internal, non-public project. I should note that I'm using Thymeleaf, though, if that makes any difference. It shouldn't be hard to reproduce. Just have `controller1` manually `model.addAttribute("foobar", val)` in the service method and expose it using `@ModelAttribute("foobar")` before calling `return "view1"`. You'll see that the Thymeleaf `view1` can access `foobar`. But if you instead `return "redirect:view1"` then `view1` can no longer see `foobar`. But if `view1` does a `POST` to `controller2`, then `controller2` (using `@SessionAttributes`) can see `foobar`!